# How to get "leveltitle" for HMENU items via TypoScript?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x, typo3-10.x

I have a menu (HMENU with `special = updated`) that gives me the latest sub and sub-sub pages from 3 categories.
The page structure looks like this in the backend:

[image]

In addition to the title, I would like to output the name of the respective category (the parent level-1 page).

This is my TypoScript attempt:

```
lib.myMenu = HMENU
lib.myMenu {
    special = updated
    special{
        value.field = 10,11,12
        beginAtLevel = 1
        limit = 99
    }
    1 = TMENU
    1{
        NO{
            doNotLinkIt = 1
            stdWrap.cObject = COA
            stdWrap.cObject {
                10 = TEXT
                10{
                    wrap = <h3>|</h3>
                    field = seo_title // title
                    typolink.parameter.field = uid
                }

                20 = HMENU
                20{
                    wrap = <div class="category attempt-1">|</div>
                    special = rootline
                    special.range = 1|1
                    special.value.field = uid # does not work
                    1 = TMENU
                    1.NO.allWrap = |
                }

                30 = TEXT
                30{
                    wrap = <div class="category attempt-2">|</div>
                    data = leveltitle : 1 # does not work as expected
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it does not work, because …

1. `special = rootline` does not support `special.value`.
2. `data = leveltitle : 1` uses the ID of the current page, instead of the TMENU item ID.

Does anyone have another approach how I can get the title of the respective category using TypoScript?

### Edit: Background information / what this is needed for

With this menu I intend to replace the news module ext:news of an existing project. Instead of news records, pages are now used and this menu creates the list view. Of course a TypoScript page browser will be added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a pure TypoScript solution that may not be very elegant, but it works:

```
lib.myMenu = HMENU
lib.myMenu {
    special = updated
    special{
        value.field = 10,11,12
        beginAtLevel = 1
        limit = 99
    }
    1 = TMENU
    1{
        NO{
            doNotLinkIt = 1
            stdWrap.cObject = COA
            stdWrap.cObject {
                10 = TEXT
                10{
                    wrap = <h3>|</h3>
                    field = seo_title // title
                    typolink.parameter.field = uid
                }

                20 = HMENU
                20{
                    wrap = <div class="category">|</div>
                    special = list
                    special.value.field = pid
                    1 = TMENU
                    1{
                        NO{
                            doNotLinkIt = 1
                            stdWrap.override{
                                # Overwrite it if we are not yet at the category level
                                if{
                                    # The ID of the page parent to the categories ("Website") is 1618
                                    equals = 1618
                                    value.field = pid
                                    negate = 1
                                }
                                cObject = HMENU
                                cObject{
                                    special = list
                                    special.value.field = pid
                                    1 = TMENU
                                    1.NO.doNotLinkIt = 1
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If the menu is to go over further levels, the override must of course be nested even deeper.

**Edit – Improvements:**

---

**RECORDS instead of HMENU:** Bernd Wilke suggested in the comments to use CONTENT instead of HMENU to generate the category title. This caused problems in my tests when sysfolders (as subpages of the categories) were used to structure the items. This could be related to the bug/feature [#20933](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/20933) (Enable working with SysFolders in CONTENT). But RECORDS might be comparable. I tried it and was able to improve the render times a little bit (see table below).

```
lib.myMenu.1.NO.stdWrap.cObject.20 = RECORDS
lib.myMenu.1.NO.stdWrap.cObject.20{
    stdWrap.wrap = <div class="category">|</div>
    source.field = pid
    tables = pages
    conf.pages = TEXT
    conf.pages {
        field = seo_title // title
        stdWrap.override{
            # Overwrite it if we are not yet at the category level
            if{
                # The ID of the page parent to the categories ("Website") is 1618
                equals = 1618
                value.field = pid
                negate = 1
            }
            cObject = RECORDS
            cObject{
                source.field = pid
                tables = pages
                conf.pages = TEXT
                conf.pages.field = seo_title // title
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**CONTENT instead of HMENU:** if no sysfolders are needed (as of TYPO3 10.4 sysfolders should also work)

```
lib.myMenu.1.NO.stdWrap.cObject.20 = CONTENT
lib.myMenu.1.NO.stdWrap.cObject.20{
    stdWrap.wrap = <div class="category">|</div>
    table = pages
    select {
        uidInList.field = pid
        pidInList = 0
        selectFields = uid, pid, seo_title, title
    }
    renderObj = TEXT
    renderObj {
        field = seo_title // title
        stdWrap.override{
            # Overwrite it if we are not yet at the category level
            if{
                # The ID of the page parent to the categories ("Website") is 1618
                equals = 1618
                value.field = pid
                negate = 1
            }
            cObject = CONTENT
            cObject{
                table = pages
                select {
                    uidInList.field = pid
                    pidInList = 0
                    selectFields = uid, pid, seo_title, title
                }
                renderObj = TEXT
                renderObj.field = seo_title // title
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**userFunc instead of HMENU:** Bernd Wilke suggested in his answer to use a userfunction. Even if this is not a pure TypoScript solution, I would have liked to test it to be able to compare the performance. The method getRootLine() has unfortunately [been marked as deprecated](https://api.typo3.org/9.5/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_frontend_1_1_page_1_1_page_repository.html#abb59d67238b30c7c054c1ba7acb8c102). Since I'm not an extension developer, it's not clear to me yet how to read the category via a userFunc and if this is actually more effective. If I still come across a solution regarding this, it will be added here.

---

**Rendertime:** I have test-implemented the menu in the live site (in the existing template) and compared the website render times with and without the output of the categories to see how much the nested menu affects the performance. The values are average values from 10 measurements. I also limited the output to 20 items, which should be a more realistic value per page later on:

| mode | 20 items | 100 items |
| --- | --- | --- |
| without category | 99 ms | 218 ms |
| categories via HMENU | 133 ms | 353 ms |
| categories via RECORDS | 132 ms | 331 ms |
| categories via CONTENT | 121 ms | 255 ms |
| categories via userFunc | TBD | TBD |

Comment: using `HMENU` instead of `TT_CONTENT` probably will be more work for the server. and what you still miss is the decision how 'deep' you need to `override`. Either you have a value for the initial page, or you have an abort condition if you match a category page (something like page-uid in set of category-uids). As you have no recursion loops in typoscript it will become a monster with boxed objects and the same condition on every level. (at least work with a prototype `temp.getcat` and further copy actions `10 < temp.getcat`, `10.override < temp.getcat`, `10.override.override < temp.getcat`)

Comment: You are absolutely right. The limited menu depth is a disadvantage and the performance might also suffer a bit. I can cope with the limited menu depth (I added in the question again what I need the menu for: it should be a news list view). I measured the render times and added them in this answer. I would like to compare this with your suggestion, please see my newest comment in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would not rebuild the complete menu item generation (`NO.doNotLinkIt = 1`).

Just use `NO.after.cObject = COA`.

`leveltitle : 1` is correct if you want to have the title for the current page.

The same if you show a rootline menu: it is generated for the current page.

If you want the levelfield for another page you need to build it by yourself.

- In typoscript you might use a userfunction. (there is a core function for getting the rootline for a given page id)
- If you generate your menu with FLUID you might use a viewhelper. (You might get inspired from [this option of viewhelper `menu.directory`](https://viewhelpers.fluidtypo3.org/fluidtypo3/vhs/5.0.1/Menu/Directory.html#argument-rootLineAs) or [this option of VH `page.breadCrumb`](https://viewhelpers.fluidtypo3.org/fluidtypo3/vhs/5.0.1/Page/BreadCrumb.html#argument-rootLineAs) in `ext:vhs`.)

---

Edit:

you might store the needed information directly in the `pages`record.

add a new field to the record (or use any unused).

then make sure that each category page contains some page TS_config:

```
TCADefaults.pages.<yourfield> = CategoryName
```

With this configuration each new page below will get this value set automatically.
Of course you need to set these values for all existing pages by hand or by some manual queries.

And if the editors are to be prevented from changing this value you need to remove the field from the edit form with this TSConfig on the top-page:

```
TCEForm.pages.<yourfield>.hide= 1
```

Comment: `NO.after = COA` outputs the text "COA" in the frontend – `NO.after.cObject = COA` would work. My example above is very slimmed down: before and after the page title there is some more info, which is partly enclosed by other elements (<article> , <header>, ...), so it is easier to regenerate the title as well. Thanks for the hints on userfunc and ext:vhs, the former could possibly come into question. But I haven't given up hope yet to find a pure TypoScript solution.

Comment: I inserted the missing `.cObject`. thanks. the only solution with pure typoscript coming to mind is a monster and probably very slow. you have to build the individual rootlines with boxed `TT_CONTENT` objects for each menu entry. and you need to decide the level of the page to calculate by yourself how 'deep' you need to box the `TT_CONTENT`s. That and the available core function are the reasons a PHP solution is easier.

Comment: added a data solution

Comment: Thank you Bernd. I found a solution with a nested menu, see my own answer. It's not very elegant and I'm not sure it's the most performant solution, but for now it works. Your solution with the database field is also interesting and certainly a bit faster. But the category would not be updated when the page is moved, right?

Comment: I would like to compare the render times of your solutions with my nested menu. I assume with TT_CONTENT objects you mean [CONTENT](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/ContentObjects/Content/Index.html), right? How could such a one be constructed? I don't know how to nest it with that yet. Even though I am a big fan of pure TypoScript solutions (I am not an extension developer), I would like to test the userFunc once. Do you know what the function is called that I can use to get to it?

Comment: of course it's [`CONTENT`](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/9.5/en-us/ContentObjects/Content/Index.html). The recursion will be done in the [renderObj](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/9.5/en-us/ContentObjects/Content/Index.html#renderobj). The PHP function is: [getrootline()](https://api.typo3.org/9.5/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_frontend_1_1_page_1_1_page_repository.html#abb59d67238b30c7c054c1ba7acb8c102)

Comment: CONTENT didn't work in my case (see my answer), but the suggestion got me to RECORDS. That sped it up a bit. Thank you for all the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You should neither use a separate HMENU nor a userFunc but a simple LOAD_REGISTER within the menu items of the parent level. This generates register entries, that can be added, changed or restored while looping through the different levels of the HMENU structure.

So you don't need the custom code of a PHP function and you won't get the performance penalty of a nested HMENU.

Basically it's shown in the official documentation, but with a CSS class instead of a title. But of course you could hand over other information from the parent to its children the same way.

Here is the example:

```
10 = COA
10 {
    ### left menu table column
    10 = LOAD_REGISTER
    10 {
        ulClass = col-left
    }

    ### right menu table column
    20 = LOAD_REGISTER
    20 {
        ulClass = col-right
    }

    30 = HMENU
    30 {
        special = list
        special.value = 1
        1 = TMENU
        # ...
        3 = TMENU
        3 {
            stdWrap {
                preCObject = COA
                preCObject {
                    10 = RESTORE_REGISTER
                }
                dataWrap = <ul class="{register:ulClass}">|</ul>
            }
            wrap =
            SPC = 1
            SPC {
                allStdWrap {
                    replacement {
                        10 {
                            search = ---
                            replace =
                        }
                    }
                    dataWrap = </ul>|<ul class="{register:ulClass}">
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here the link to the full documentation page:
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/UsingSetting/Register.html

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand exactly how to get the title of the parent level-1 page into a register. By "different levels of the HMENU structure" you mean TMENU levels, right? Since it is a menu of type `special = updated`, I have only one TMENU level, which includes pages from different page tree depths.

Comment: OK - then forget about that approach. I just forgot that the updated special menu is limited to a single rendering level.